# Is the + operator the only operator that is able to modify a string while keeping it as a string?

Tags: javascript, string, operators

I'm going through this javascript course https://javascript.info/operators
I noticed that when you use operators like *, /, -, the string won't remain a string but instead will be converted. So my question leads to this. Is the plus(+) operator the only operator that is able to modify a string and afterwards it will remain a string?

Comment: Well, the grouping operator will also leave it unchanged `("hello")`

Comment: Ironically, unary `+` is used to convert a string to number.

Comment: Actually, making a full list of operators that don't change a string is not that easy. There is many of them - grouping, comma, conditional, assignment (at least `=` and `+=`), relational operators, equality operators (maybe except loose equality in some circumstances), logical operators (in a lot of circumstances). Just off the top of my head. Do you want the full list?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes that would be nice

Comment: There is no operator that will modify a string, because strings are immutable. The diad + operator is the only operator that returns a string in a lot of cases. There is a very long list of operators that just evaluate to one of their operands, so if you pass in a string they'll also return one (VLAZ mentioned a few). I don't see a reason to maintain a list of these operators here though, at it is a quite unuseful subset of all JS operators.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the only operator. There are many that will not [type coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion). Depends on how strictly you want to define this, however, in some cases, there is a coercion happening but the end result is the original type.

Here is a list:

## Unary operators

### [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

The operator can remove properties from objects.

No type coercion is performed but the operation is meaningless. Calling `delete` on a string literal is a no-op.

```js
"use strict";

delete "hello";
console.log("---")
```

Calling `delete` on a variable is a no-op *in loose mode* but throws an error in strict mode.

```js
"use strict";

let foo = "world";

delete foo;

console.log(foo);
```

### [Grouping `()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping)

The grouping operator doesn't change anything about the expression given. It can only change the order of evaluation, if needed. The result of the grouping operator is *always* the same as the expression inside it.

### [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

It returns the type of the operand given. No type coercion but the output is always a string. In the case of using `typeof` with primitive strings, the result is always going to be `"string"`.

### [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

The `void` operator takes any expression and returns `undefined`. No type coercion is involved because whatever the value, it is just swallowed.

## Binary operators

### Assignment operators

Assignment is giving a value to a variable. *Some* of the assignment operators will not perform coercion, others do.

#### No coercion: [`=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment), [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment), [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), [`&&=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment), [`||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment)

No coercion of the assigned value *if it's a string*. The logical assignments will only conditionally assign the value.

Example:

```js
//`=`, `+=`, `??=`, `&&=`, `||=`

const a = "one";

let b = "t";
b += "wo";

let c = null;
c ??= "three";

let d = true;
d &&= "four";

let e = false;
e ||= "five";

console.log(a, b, c, d, e);


let x = "hello";
x ??= "twenty four";

let y = false;
y &&= "twenty five";

let z = true;
z ||= "twenty six";

console.log(x, y, z);
```

The addition assignment will work the same as `x = x + y` which also means that it could coerce *to a string*, if one of the operands is not that:

```js
let foo = "four";
foo += 2;

let bar = 4;
bar += "two";

console.log(foo, bar);
```

#### Coercion is performed: [`*=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Multiplication_assignment), [`/=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Division_assignment), [`%=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder_assignment), [`-=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Subtraction_assignment), [`<<=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Left_shift_assignment), [`>>=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Right_shift_assignment), [`>>>=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift_assignment), [`&=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND_assignment), [`^=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR_assignment), [`|=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR_assignment), [`**=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation_assignment)

All of these will coerce the type of the operand to a number.

### Equality

#### No coercion: [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality), [`!==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_inequality)

The strict equality/inequality operators will **not** perform any type coercion. If the operands are of different types, the equality check returns `false`.

#### With coercion: [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality), [`!=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Inequality)

The *loose* equality/inequality operators ***will perform type coercion***. How and when depends on the operands given to them. For example, with a string *and a number*, the string will be coerced to a number. However, with a string *and an object*, the object will be coerced *to a primitive*. If that primitive is a number, *then* the string operand will be coerced again.

[See the loose equality algorithm for more information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#loose_equality_using)

```js
const a = "   11.";
const b = 11;

console.log("a == b:", a == b);

const c = {
  toString() {
    return "   11.";
  }
}

console.log("a == c:", a == c);

const d = {
  valueOf() {
    return 11;
  }
}

console.log("a == d:", a == d);

const e = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return "   11.";
  }
}
const f = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return 11;
  }
}


console.log("a == e:", a == e);
console.log("a == f:", a == f);
```

### Comma [`,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

The comma operator takes two expressions and returns the second one. No type coercion is involved - it's *similar* to the `void` operator in that the value of the first expression is just discarded.

### Concatenation [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition)

The addition operator only performs concatenation if at least one of the operands is a string *when converted to a primitive*. If the other operand does not produce a string, then it's coerced to one:

```js
const a = "1";
const b = 2;

console.log("a + b:", a + b);

const c = {
  toString() {
    return "3";
  }
}

console.log("a + c:", a + c);

const d = {
  valueOf() {
    return 4;
  }
}

console.log("a + d:", a + d);

const e = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return "5";
  }
}
const f = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive]() {
    return 6;
  }
}


console.log("a + e:", a + e);
console.log("a + f:", a + f);

//two objects, where one converts to a string
console.log("!!! e + f !!!:", e + f);
```

### Logical Operators [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND), [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

The operators will check if the value is truthy or falsy. For strings, only the empty string (`""`) is falsy, all other strings are truthy. However, the *result* of the logical operators will not change the type.

```js
const a = true && "one";
const b = false || "two";
const c = null ?? "three";

console.log(a, b, c);
```

### Relational

#### No coercion: [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)

No coercion involved but some usages are meaningless.

The `instanceof` operator will never produce `true`

- if the *right* value is a string, it throws an error, as it expects a function.
- if the *left* value is a string, then it's not an instance of any other function, since it's a primitive.

Using a non-object as a right value of `in` also throws an error. It's valid as a left value and no coercion is performed.

#### Sometimes coercion is performed: [`<`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than), [`>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than), [`<=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Less_than_or_equal), [`>=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Greater_than_or_equal)

These are similar to `+` and `==` in that the operands will *sometimes* be coerced. With two strings, there is no coercion happening (similar to `+` and `==`) but otherwise an attempt will be made to convert to numbers. Objects are first converted to primitives.

## Ternary operators

### Conditional operator [`? :`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

A string as *first* operand will be checked for truthyness. If it's either of the second or third operand, then it's just returned as-is based on the condition.